Colour correction on Nvidia video
My display shows too much red. Every time I reboot, I have to run the Nvidia Xserver Settings to correct the colour. The problem was with an Nvidia GeForce 1050 with the Nvidia driver. I had to replace the video card with a GeForce 3050, and upgraded the driver to 4.6.0 NVIDIA 550.107.02, but the problem persists.
Can someone point me in the right direction as to where to look? Is there an auto-colour utility? I'm running Ubuntu 22.04

Did you check the monitor itself? Also trying checking https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-night-light.html.en

Thanks for the reply. The problem persists on my TV as well (I'm using HDMI output), so it's not the monitor.
